# Creating a linear gradient SVG filter

Tags: css, svg, gradient, mask, alpha

Essentially I'm trying to create an gradient alpha mask in using SVG and CSS ([like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yc2u2frzxcs66v4/Screenshot%202014-04-10%2009.23.41.png)), and since the `mask` property is [no longer on the standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask) track I'm exploring the [`filter` route](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

I've created a vertical alpha mask in *Sketch*, with the top being 0% `#000000` and the bottom being 100% `#000000`, then exported it as an SVG and tweaked it using guidance from [this O' Reilly article](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Filters#svgess-CHP-10-EX-14). It now looks like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <defs>
        <!-- Start by creating our vertical linear gradient -->
        <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="alphaLinear">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #000000; stop-opacity: 0%;" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #000000; stop-opacity: 100%;" />
        </linearGradient>

        <!-- Create a rectangle and apply the gradient as its fill -->
        <rect id="boxRect" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="200" style="fill: url(#alphaLinear);" />

        <!-- Using that rectangle, we'll create a filter -->
        <filter id="alphaGrad">
            <feImage xlink:href="#boxRect" result="grad"/>
            <feDisplacementMap scale="10" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in="SourceGraphic" in2="grad"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <use id="gradientBox" fill="url(#alphaGradient)" xlink:href="#boxRect"></use>

</svg>
```

My knowledge of SVG isn't the greatest so I'm suspecting this is where I've gone wrong.

Next, I applied the filter using `filter` (and `-webkit-filter`) along with referencing the filter ID `#alphaGrad`:

```
-webkit-filter: url('http://blahblah.com/alphagradient.svg#alphaGrad');
```

But, of course, this it doesn't work. Can anyone help me get the hang of this? Or is this even possible? If not, can someone recommend a method of how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Update: [here's a pretty basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/T488Z/2/) of what I'm doing...

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle?

Comment: Yup! Added the fiddle above!

Comment: What are you trying to do? The goal is to display a gradient above the image?

Comment: The goal is to use SVG as a mask (via `filter`), but use an alpha gradient as the mask's fill. Check out the link in my first paragraph above - It's tricky to describe, but I'd like to "fade to transparency". But yes, it would mask an image, or text.

Comment: I meant a fiddle including the SVG. I placed one here: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/T488Z/2/

Comment: Ahhh, sorry about that. It's updated above.

Comment: 'mask' is part of SVG 1.1 so at least inside of svg it's safe to use. For the next level of 'mask', see http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/, which is where these -webkit prefixes came from.

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors and misconceptions in your example (why did you think a displacementMap would help you?)

Why don't you start from the code below - pure SVG using an SVG mask and an SVG image.

```
<svg width="600px" height="600px" viewbox="0 0 600 600">

    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="alphaLinear">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="0%" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#999999" stop-opacity="100%" />
        </linearGradient>

        <mask id="Mask">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600" fill="url(#alphaLinear)"  />
        </mask>

    </defs>

    <image xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Anadama_bread_(1).jpg" width="600" height="600" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"     mask="url(#Mask)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm just beginning to learn about SVG, I used a displacementMap purely because the O' Reilly article mentioned above had a working example with one. Unfortunately I don't think I can use your example above because in order to use the `filter` property in CSS I need to reference an actual Filter within the SVG. Right? haha I could be completely wrong!

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure how this would help gradient mask blocks of content within my markup - such as the top of an entire `div` with text. I'm starting to wonder if what I'm trying to do is possible...

Comment: If you need it to apply to general HTML content, then I'm pretty sure that this is only currently possible in Firefox. As of a few months ago, at least, Chrome/Safari did not allow the use of the filter primitives you will need to use (compositing/blending) within a webkit-filter

Comment: Alright, no problem. Just wanted to explore this :)

Answer (score 0):

Few remarks:

1. SVG (and CSS) [`opacity` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Content_type#Opacity_value) is not percertentual range but 0.0 - 1.0 range.
2. Mentioned `mask` property appears to be just prefixed in Webkit and unprefixed in Gecko.
3. If your target environment is HTML + CSS, you might not necessarily need SVG: you could get similar effect using linear-gradient and RGBA
   `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);` on some overlay (pseudo) element. `pointer-events: none;` could be useful then.